# Meaning of 鼻を鳴らす?

Tags: translation, set-phrases, literature

I am reading 煙草と悪魔　by Akutagawa, and came across a phrase which has me stumped. The sentence reads as follows:

> 伊留満は、これを聞くと、小さな眼を輝かせて、二三度、満足さうに、鼻を鳴らした。"

My current understanding of this sentence is:
"The priest, with a glint in his eye, appeared content after hearing the answer."

I'm not certain what action the priest is taking two or three times (二三度).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action is snorting (鼻を鳴らす).

*伊留満は、これを聞くと、小さな眼を輝かせて、: When the priest heard this, his small eyes lit up,*

*二三度、満足さうに、鼻を鳴らした。: and he snorted two or three times in satisfaction.*

See the Jisho entry for [鳴らす](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%B3%B4%E3%82%89%E3%81%99):

> *1. to ring; to sound; to chime; to beat; **to snort (nose)**; to snap (fingers); to crack (joints)​*
>
> *2. to be popular; to be esteemed; to be reputed​*
>
> *3. to state; to insist; to complain​*
>
> *4. to fart (loudly) ​Archaism*